# Call jQuery plugin's method on items added dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a page where there's a button to add new content. This button adds elements to the DOM, and one of them is a bootstrap-select component.

The page always have at least one group of elements, and for this first one I can just use `class="selectpicker"` and it works fine. However, for the new items added, it doesn't work, so I think I should call the the method through javascript like  `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`

The problem is that I don't know how to trigger a function that I can call this `selectpicker()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Call selectpicker with the refresh parameter for your newly added items

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to call selectpicker method for the newly added node.
Check this out!
[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/pctC6b3Piq)